# OpenCV 3 HOG Detection confidence?

Tags: c++, opencv

I am using the OpenCV 3 HOG people detector to detect people moving in front of my laptops web cam. The detection part works sort of fine but I would like to obtain the confidence from the HOG classifier, which I think should be possible.

I use the following code to obtain the bounding boxes for the detected objects:

```
std::vector< cv::Rect> found_locations_rect;
d_hog->detectMultiScale(rGpuImg, found_locations_rect);
```

According to the Intellisense tip it should be possible to extract the confidence using:

```
void detectMultiScale(cv::InputArray img, std::vector<cv::Rect> &found_locations, std::vector<double> *confidence = (std::vector<double> *)0);
```

But I am not sure how to declare and initialize the *confidence variable, can you please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look at [official OpenCV documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d5/d33/structcv_1_1HOGDescriptor.html#a1271d93ac5397bff0b1502a331613938), it declares this overload of detectMultiScale function (**CPU** implementation):

```
virtual void cv::HOGDescriptor::detectMultiScale    (   InputArray  img,
std::vector< Rect > &   foundLocations,
std::vector< double > &     foundWeights,
double  hitThreshold = 0,
Size    winStride = Size(),
Size    padding = Size(),
double  scale = 1.05,
double  finalThreshold = 2.0,
bool    useMeanshiftGrouping = false 
)       const
```

and [for **GPU**](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/de/da6/classcv_1_1cuda_1_1HOG.html#af4a3bf27a5a04817c6d584d9108f50b7)

```
virtual void cv::cuda::HOG::detectMultiScale    (   InputArray  img,
std::vector< Rect > &   found_locations,
std::vector< double > *     confidences = NULL 
)
```

So you can simply call it (**CPU** mode):

```
std::vector< cv::Rect> found_locations_rect;
std::vector<double> found_weights;
d_hog->detectMultiScale(mat, found_locations_rect, found_weights);
```

or (**GPU** implementation):

```
std::vector< cv::Rect> found_locations_rect;
std::vector<double> confidences;
d_hog->detectMultiScale(rGpuImg, found_locations_rect, &confidences);
```

And if it will not work, OpenCV will throw an exception. You can display it like this:

```
try
{
    std::vector< cv::Rect> found_locations_rect;
    std::vector<double> confidences;
    d_hog->detectMultiScale(rGpuImg, found_locations_rect, &confidences);
}
catch(const std::exception& e)
{
    std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
}
```

After that you can solve the problem

Comment: Thanks but I am getting the following exception thrown:

Comment: Exception thrown at 0x00007FFA8C537788 in HOG_GPU.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x0000005431F0E690.
Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFA8C537788 in HOG_GPU.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x0000005431F0E690.

Comment: @ErikS, if you have an exception - show us its text

Comment: The exception is:Exception thrown at 0x00007FFA8C537788 in HOG_GPU.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x0000005D5CBEEB50.
Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFA8C537788 in HOG_GPU.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x0000005D5CBEEB50.

Comment: no. not the address of exception - but terminal output when exception occur. what is "inside" exception?

Comment: I am not sure how to get the info you need. But this is the terminal output: "OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (confidence == NULL || group_threshold_ == 0) in 'Anonymous-namespace' :: HOG_Impl::detectMultiScale" Is this the info you needed?